# Defusing Binary Bomb Phase 5

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm super stuck on the infamous bomb lab. Not asking anyone to give me the answer straight but if someone could point me in the right direction that'd be great. Honestly I'm really lost at to what I'm even trying to do here but I do know I need a lookup table and to somehow create a six digit string that is equivalent 0x30.

**Disassembly code**

```
 0x0000000000401007 <+0>:     push   %rbx
 0x0000000000401008 <+1>:     mov    %rdi,%rbx
 0x000000000040100b <+4>:     callq  0x401241 <string_length>
 0x0000000000401010 <+9>:     cmp    $0x6,%eax
 0x0000000000401013 <+12>:    je     0x40101a <phase_5+19>
 0x0000000000401015 <+14>:    callq  0x4014c4 <explode_bomb>
 0x000000000040101a <+19>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
 0x000000000040101f <+24>:    mov    $0x0,%edx
 0x0000000000401024 <+29>:    movzbl (%rbx,%rax,1),%ecx
 0x0000000000401028 <+33>:    and    $0xf,%ecx
 0x000000000040102b <+36>:    add    0x4024a0(,%rcx,4),%edx
 0x0000000000401032 <+43>:    add    $0x1,%rax
 0x0000000000401036 <+47>:    cmp    $0x6,%rax
 0x000000000040103a <+51>:    jne    0x401024 <phase_5+29>
 0x000000000040103c <+53>:    cmp    $0x30,%edx
 0x000000000040103f <+56>:    je     0x401046 <phase_5+63>
 0x0000000000401041 <+58>:    callq  0x4014c4 <explode_bomb>
 0x0000000000401046 <+63>:    pop    %rbx
 0x0000000000401047 <+64>:    retq

(gdb) x/16xd 0x4024a0
0x4024a0 <array.3155>:          2       10      6       1
0x4024b0 <array.3155+16>:       12      16      9       3
0x4024c0 <array.3155+32>:       4       7       14      5
0x4024d0 <array.3155+48>:       11      8       15      13
```

Comment: You need to select 6 numbers from the table that sum to `0x30`. Then pick input letters such that the low 4 bits of the ascii code give the position in the table for each one.

Comment: @Jester So, for example 12, 12, 6, 6, 6, 6 or 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 would work from the table. Then the low four bits that correspond to the indices for those numbers in the lookup table. 12 is index 4, 6 is index 2, and 8 is index 13. So I need to find an ascii character with the low 4 bit of 0100, 0010, or 1101?

Comment: Or is it the hex low 4 bit, so 0x04, 0x02, 0x0d, etc?

Comment: Those are the same :) Yeah picking 8 six times is the easiest.

Comment: Oops, duh. So in this case m six times(ascii code 0x6d/01101101) should work -- however I'm not getting a defusal notification. Am I still missing something? I really appreciate the help by the way :)

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. Had to wait for it to finish looping - silly mistake. Thanks so much for your help.